# Stop Wordpress 3.9 From Removing Line Breaks

Tags: javascript, php, html, wordpress

When im using the tinymce in wordpress, I like to use the visual editor to add color and font styles and things, and then sometimes I like to get right in there and do a little html editing so the post turns out out I like it. But I notice now that wordpress updated to tinymce 4.0 that every time I switch between the visual editor and the html editior my br tags are removed. I know theres lots of tips on how to fix this out there but I think they are meant for earlier versions on tinymc since none of them seem to work for me, even the plugins out there don't seem to work ...
 Any Thoughts ?

Comment: you just insert a carriage return and it interprets it as a line break, the <br> is unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

Install [ckeditor](http://wordpress.org/plugins/ckeditor-for-wordpress/) plugin for wordpress and then you can use source mode provided by  ckeditor.